# Reference custom resource defined in another xaml file

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, staticresource

I am trying to create a new resource in one xaml file and reference it in another xaml file.
i.e I define

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="TileBrush" TileMode="Tile" ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewport="0 0 32 32" ImageSource="MyImageButton.png" Opacity="0.3">
    </ImageBrush>
</Window.Resources>
```

And attempt to use it in another xaml file by

```
<Grid>
    <Button Background="{StaticResource TileBrush}" Margin="5" Padding="5" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14">
        A Tiled Button
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

However I get the error *"StaticResource reference 'TileBrush' was not found."*
I can reference the resource from the same xaml file but don't know how to do so from another file.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/03/creating-and-consuming-resource-dictionaries-in-wpf-and-silverlight.aspx

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In WPF, the resource references works as a tree. Each control have resource, and children control can access parent's resources. The global application resource dictionary is in the App.xaml file. In this file you can include several resource dictionaries as a Merged Dictionary. See this code sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application ...>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="View\SomeFileDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

The `SomeFileDictionary.xaml` is located in the `View` folder of my project structure. And has looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:Cepha.ViewModel"
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                ... >

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:SomeType}">
    <TextBox .../>
</DataTemplate>...
```

And each dictionary key or data template defined in this file (or App.xaml), can be referenced in any place of your project. Hope this helps...

Comment: There is a template for a `Resource Dictionary`. I found it in the `Add New Item` dialog in the `Windows Store Group`.

Comment: Yes, and also, if you add a resource dictionary using the Blend template, it also creates the merged dictionaries...

Comment: how would you do this with a class library?

Answer (score 0):

You should define this in the app.xaml file. These resources are shared throughout the entire project